# Resolve a custom membership provider using unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have a custom membership provider which works fine until I use unity in the web application.

```
public class CustomMemberProvider : MembershipProvider
```

I have done some googling and found the snippet below to place in the application_start() of the global file but I am not sure what I need to do to it to make it work for my custom provider. Basically when I make a call on validateUser() on my security controller it fails to resolve the dependencies.

```
        _container.RegisterType<IFormsAuthenticationService, FormsAuthenticationService>()
        .RegisterType<IMembershipService, AccountMembershipService>()
        .RegisterInstance<MembershipProvider>(Membership.Provider);
```

I thought I could swap "AccountMembershipService" for "CustomMemberProvider" but that causes the Controller Type to be null in the standard "UnityControllerFactory".

Has anyone had the same problems?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AccountMembershipService is probably the same service that VS generates.  This service implements IMembershipService (a custom interface generated by the code).  Simply swapping out AccountMembershipService for CustomMemberProvider is not going to be the same thing.

Essentially, your custom membership provider implements the abstract class "MembershipProvider" which is different than this "AccountMembershipService" which is a wrapper to SqlMembershipProvider.

You need to make a wrapper to your membership provider to implement a type.  Also, I'm pretty sure Membership.Provider is going to take you to System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider and not your custom provider.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The CustomMemberProvider inherits MembershipProvider and overrides the methods. I have a CustomMembershipService which implements IMembershipService and I have registered the CustomMemberProvider in the Webconfig instead of the default one. Still not resolving the dependencies in the security controller.

Comment: Can you post a little more code, preferrably what all those objects are and at least thier namespaces as well as the includes in your global.ascx?